# Universal approximation theorem for neural networks reference

Tags: neural-networks, references, approximation

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem#Arbitrary-width_case), a nice theorem is given:
[image]

However, I can not find the stated theorem in the given references. So where is the stated theorem from?